# getOptions return an empty array in my Magento 2.1.10

Tags: product-attribute

I cannot manage to show custom attributes in my site anymore.

It occurs after an upgrade from  a previous version  (2.1.2)

Can someone take a look and help me? I do not know what to try anymore

thanks
mf

Comment: What is your current magento version? are those attributes visible in admin section?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run following commands and then check.

> **php bin/magento indexer:reindex**
>
> **php bin/magento cache:clean**

Comment: already tried, no result

Comment: in 

/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options.phtml

the function $block->getOptions() returns an empty array